# SPD custom workflow takes more time to resume than expected...?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a custom workflow designed on SP designer with few sequence of actions. In one of the step, trying to pause the workflow for few mins(5mins) however noticed that it is taking more time to resume.

What could be the issue? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on when the workflow timer service runs, it can take longer than 5 minutes for your pause to unpause and resume.  You can set the timer service to run more frequently.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424970.aspx